# Store JSONObject in Google Datastore using Java

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My application deals with JSON metadata which can have any fields, not a defined structure. 
I want to store incoming JSON into google datastore as JSON objects.

I tried to save `org.json.JSONObject`, but it does not work.

How to store JSON objects inside Google Datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wont be able to query the json fields, just store it as a text string. Beware of entity maximum size.

Comment: You mean storing JSON as blob(support maximum size). Get and parse into JSON object whenever need it. Will it be effective method?

Comment: Yes. Will work as long as you dont need to query based on json fields